# Adding custom CKEditor to Angular app

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

Basically I want to build an angular app with a text editor which supports syntax highlighting for a `Dockerfile`.

I'm fairly new to Angular, I downloaded a custom `highlight.js` to serve my purpose.

I'm not sure if and how to add it to an editor (say CKEditor) to support the syntax highlighting part. And how to further add this editor to my angular app.

I have no idea how to work with it, nor could I find any reasonable tutorials.

Comment: You can try angular semmernote.

Comment: Did you get that to work for you yet? I could help if you still need that.

Comment: @mohsenmadi Yes, I did. Although I ended up using CodeMirror. Thanks :)